# Play music button won't work on google sites

Tags: html, audio, sites

This works fine on my google blog, but won't work on google sites. Any ideas why?

```
<audio controls="controls" height="100" width="100">
<source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
<source src="horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
<embed height="100" width="100" src="horse.mp3">
</audio>
```

Answer (score 0):

Belatedly... I think is is part of Google Sites' general hostility to audio. GS even refuses to play attached MP3 and WAV: http://img542.imageshack.us/img542/4215/h87b.png .

However it does tolerate this:

```
<img src="https://www.google.com/chart?chc=sites&amp;cht=d&amp;chdp=sites&amp;chl=%5B%5BGoogle+Gadget'%3D20'f%5Cv'a%5C%3D0'10'%3D359'0'dim'%5Cbox1'b%5CF6F6F6'fC%5CF6F6F6'eC%5C0'sk'%5C%5B%22Google+Audio+Player.+Advance+by+step.%22'%5D'a%5CV%5C%3D12'f%5C%5DV%5Cta%5C%3D10'%3D0'%3D360'%3D32'dim'%5C%3D10'%3D10'%3D360'%3D32'vdim'%5Cbox1'b%5Cva%5CF6F6F6'fC%5CC8C8C8'eC%5C'a%5C%5Do%5CLauto'f%5C&amp;sig=ZEkDBX01MSrDBRH3BCPM1VTOfok" data-igsrc="http://172.gmodules.com/ig/ifr?mid=172&amp;synd=trogedit&amp;url=http%3A%2F%2Fprac-gadget.googlecode.com%2Ffiles%2Fgoogle-audio-step.xml&amp;up_MP3=https%3A%2F%2Fsites.google.com%2Fsite%2Fcjjtestsite%2FHome%2Fhorse.mp3&amp;up_START=&amp;up_CCOL=%23d1dae3&amp;h=35&amp;w=360" data-type="ggs-gadget" data-props="align:left;borderTitle:Google Audio Player. Advance by step.;height:35;igsrc:http#58//172.gmodules.com/ig/ifr?mid=172&amp;synd=trogedit&amp;url=http%3A%2F%2Fprac-gadget.googlecode.com%2Ffiles%2Fgoogle-audio-step.xml&amp;up_MP3=https%3A%2F%2Fsites.google.com%2Fsite%2Fcjjtestsite%2FHome%2Fhorse.mp3&amp;up_START=&amp;up_CCOL=%23d1dae3&amp;h=35&amp;w=360;mid:172;scrolling:no;showBorder:false;showBorderTitle:null;spec:http#58//prac-gadget.googlecode.com/files/google-audio-step.xml;up_CCOL:#35d1dae3;up_MP3:https#58//sites.google.com/site/cjjtestsite/Home/horse.mp3;up_START:;width:360;wrap:false;" width="360" height="35" style="display:block;text-align:left;margin-right:auto;" class="igm"></div>
```

Sorry not to have a more useful answer!